# Computing $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha n +1}}$ where $\alpha>0$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to calculate $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha n +1}};\;\; \alpha>0$$
using the fact that 
$$\frac{1}{1-a}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{a^k}+\frac{a^n}{1-a}$$
So taking $a=-t^\alpha$ we get
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+t^\alpha}dt=\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha n +1}}+(-1)^n\int_0^1{\frac{t^{\alpha n}}{1+t^\alpha}dt}$$
It remains to calculate $(-1)^n\int_0^1{\frac{t^{\alpha n}}{1+t^\alpha}dt}$ and show that it goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ but i can't go further, thank you for your help to continue this or if there is another way to do it.

Comment: The sum can be expressed in terms of [Digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). You can use following expansion of digamma function: $$\psi(z) = -\gamma + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+z}\right)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More directly, for every $n\geqslant0$,
$$
\frac1{an+1}=\int_0^1t^{an}\mathrm dt,
$$
hence, the series being alternated (meaning, alternating signs and decreasing absolute values),
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{(-1)^n}{an+1}=\int_0^1\sum_{n\geqslant0}(-1)^nt^{an}\mathrm dt=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t^a}.
$$
**Nota:** About the mention that:

> It remains to calculate $(-1)^n\int_0^1{\frac{t^{\alpha n}}{1+t^\alpha}dt}$ and show that it goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Well, $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{t^{\alpha n}}{1+t^\alpha}\mathrm dt\leqslant\int_0^1t^{\alpha n}\mathrm dt=\frac1{\alpha n+1}$ hence this seems clear.